# Way to retract bad edit in review queue?

Tags: support, editing

I realized after I submitted an edit that it sucked. It was held for review due to my lack of privileges. I wasn't able to find a way to undo it from the UI I can get at, is there a way for me to undo it myself?

Answer (score 4):

You can’t retract an edit (unfortunately) but you can click on the post’s edit button to edit your edit. You still have to meet the requirements for suggesting an edit (6+ characters changed) but often you can edit to make the post clearer so that fewer people make the same mistake you made while reading the post.

(It’s not a big deal if a wrong edit gets approved because it can easily be handled via rollbacks or retrospectively rejecting it. It just should be handled promptly.)